# Chrome - Check if reload is pressed

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

How can I check using Jquery if chrome reload button is pressed?

I have a form post request on a page and when I click the back button its asking "Confirm form submission"..

Now when I need to identify the reload button in my jquery?

Comment: It's not possible in client-side code. The browser's own interface is beyond the document and cannot be reached. You can only know that the user is navigating away from the current instance of the page ([`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload), [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload)). Note: If you're developing a browser extension, the answer may be different, but you should specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a $_SESSION like function like in php?

```
 if (!empty($_SESSION['visited_pages'])) {
        $_SESSION['visited_pages']['prev'] = $_SESSION['visited_pages']['current'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['visited_pages']['prev'] = 'No previous page';
    }
        $_SESSION['visited_pages']['current'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I use this to keep track of my pages, and for your case you would just need to see if the prev page is the same as the current page.

Comment: ...but the OP never mentions PHP (or any other server side script).

Comment: @JohnBupit Yes you are right but I provided more info than anyone else has. and perhaps I can give him an idea.

None the less though, you are right he didn't say anything about php.

Comment: The question is _How can I check using **Jquery** if chrome reload button is pressed?_